# Syntax for reusable iterable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax, iterator, iterable

When you use a generator comprehension, you can only use the iterable once. For example.

```
>>> g = (i for i in xrange(10))
>>> min(g)
0
>>> max(g)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

Which is kind of annoying considering that works differently than list comprehensions.

You could do `g = lambda (): (i for i in xrange(10))` to make it reusable, but then you have to do `g ()` instead of `g` (EDIT: The problem with this isn't that `g ()` is too long to type, but that if a function expects an iterable, you can't tell it to do `g ()` instead of `g.__iter__()`). You could also do

```
class gObject(object):
    def __iter__(self): return (i for i in xrange(10))

g = gObject()
```

but that is significantly longer than typing `g = (i for i in xrange(10))`. Is there a shorter syntax than `gObject` to accomplish this task?

Notes:

- We may assume that the iterable will not consume elements from other permanent  iterables. For example, if I did `z = iter(xrange(10))`, I would not try to define `g = (i for i in z)`, since that could only work once (without cloning `z`).
- `g` will no longer be an iterator. Rather, it will now be an iterable. I am fine with that. Indeed, that is kind of the point.
- It should work for infinite iterables. For example, a list comprehension would not work since it only works in finite cases.
- We may assume that any initialization costs are cheap, so rerunning the code defining `g` would not be an issue.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186751/discussion-on-question-by-pyrulez-syntax-for-reusable-iterable).

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully follow the comments, but `itertools.tee` can give me multiple iterables:

```
In [518]: g1,g2,g3 = itertools.tee((i for i in range(10)), 3)
In [519]: min(g1), max(g2)
Out[519]: (0, 9)
In [520]: a = 0
In [521]: while a<10:
     ...:     a += next(g3)      # simulate an infinite sequence
     ...:     
In [522]: a
Out[522]: 10
In [523]: list(g3)
Out[523]: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Or without unpacking:

```
def foo(g):
    a=0
    while a<12:
        a += next(g)
    return (a, list(g))

In [525]: alist = itertools.tee((i for i in range(10)),3)
     ...: flist = [min, max, foo]
     ...: for f,a in zip(flist, alist):
     ...:     print(f(a))
0
9
(15, [6, 7, 8, 9])
```

(This is using Py3)

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no syntax that is more concise, because what you are asking for is a very niche case and not one for which Python chooses to give special support.