# Python reset or reuse custom range class

Tags: python, range, generator

Example custom range class is not reset or "reusable" like builtin range. How to make it so?

```
def exampleCustomRange(stopExclusive):
  for i in range(stopExclusive):
    yield i

>> builtinRange = range(3)
>> [x for x in builtinRange]
[0, 1, 2]
>> [x for x in builtinRange]
[0, 1, 2] # See how this repeats on a second try? It is reusable or reset.
>> customRange = exampleCustomRange(3)
>> [x for x in customRange]
[0, 1, 2]
>> [x for x in customRange]
[] # See how this is now empty? It is not reusable or reset.
```

The second use of customRange shown in repl above does not repeat, reset, or reuse like the builtin range. I want to match the behavior of the builtinRange.

Comment: Wouldn't using `range` be the best way "to match the behavior of the builtinRange"?

Comment: You can use `itertools.cycle(range(3))`

Comment: @AndrejKesely That's not equivalent.

Comment: Related questions: [Reusable unbounded range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49475920/364696), [Syntax for reusable iterable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54208566/364696).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you bring in your example is just a "generator function" - which will create a single-use iterator each time it is called.

Bult-in `range` is actually a class, that will annotate its given parameters as internal state, and create a new generator each time that is requested.

This should work as you expect, instead:

```
class ExampleCustomRange:
    def __init__(self, stop_exclusive):
        self.stop_exclusive = stop_exclusive

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(self.stop_exclusive):
           yield i
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple class implementing the [iterator protocol](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_iterators.asp) would do the trick:

```
class exampleCustomRange:
    def __init__(self, stop):
        self.stop = stop

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(self.stop):
            yield i

>>> e = exampleCustomRange(3)
>>> list(e)
[0, 1, 2]
>>> list(e)
[0, 1, 2]
>>> list(e)
[0, 1, 2]
```

The main difference is that the `__iter__` method is called for every *new* iteration of `e`, thus returning a fresh generator each time.
In the plain generator function that you tried, the function is only called once.

Comment: Simplify further, and just make the body of `__iter__`  `yield from range(self.stop)` or `return iter(range(self.stop))` (the latter if nothing else must be done, the former if you might need to `yield` other things along with whatever the `range` produces).

Comment: the fact the OP brought up an example with a simple "range" use just reflects a very nice minimal reproducible example by their part. The final custom "range" thing the O.P. intents is most certainly not mirroring range, and doing anything different from what is in this example would just increase coupling and diminish readability